# Android ImageView in XML leak when load large Image

Tags: android, android-imageview, out-of-memory

This is my ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ads"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/my_img" />
```

If my_img is 3200px x 480px.

Can my ImageView leak?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory leaks typically happen when some object that lives longer than your `Activity` keeps a reference to your image, your `ImageView` or `Activity`. So, if you avoid that, you should be fine.

On a side note, on Gingerbread and up, a 3200px by 480px will occupy about 6MB of memory when decoded (3200 * 480 * 4 bytes/pixel = about 5.8MB [[source]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html)).  That is not enought to put you in danger of tipping your memory quota even on very old devices, assuming things are being properly cleaned up. Also, a courtesy call to [Bitmap.recycle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29)  can be helpful when you know you no longer need a Bitmap (but keep in mind that this is just a suggestion to clean up the Bitmap, it doesn't happen immediately).

Comment: When i gone my xml layout for the first time use, do images in this layout still decoded?